# Fractal Transformer Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I tried to transform object like as:

```
$objects = Object::all();
$objects = (new ObjectTransformer)->transform($objects);
```

Where `ObjectTransformer` is:

```
class ObjectTransformer extends TransformerAbstract {

    public function transform(Object $obj)
    {
        return [
            'id' => (int) $obj->id,
            'name' => $obj->prefix
        ];
    }
}
```

I get an error:

```
Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\API\ObjectTransformer::transform() must be an instance of App\Http\Controllers\API\Object, instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection given
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function expects an `Object` and you are passing a `Collection` of `Objects`...

But if what you want is just to transform a collection, you don't need to create a specific class, just use the `transform` Collection method with an anonymous function that does the job:

```
$objects = Object::all();
$objects->transform(function($object,$key){
    return [
        'id'=>(int)$object->id, 
        'name'=>$object->prefix
    ];
});
```

Comment: Can you explain me how to use Transformer in `Fractal\Resource\Item` when I have object: `$obj->prototypez()->get()->first(),`

Comment: I mean for nested relations

Comment: No, I just answered your question. :)